# Make Admin::routes();

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Hello everyone.
Laravel uses this for user groups

```
Auth::routes();
```

I have a rout group For webmaster
How to create a routes like the example above. As below:

```
َadmin::routes();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to provide routes via a package, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#routes.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');
}
```

If you're just doing this for organization, I don't see what benefit you get - you'd be better off putting them in something like `routes/admin.php` and loading that file in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file like the web/API routes are already.

Comment: how can I do this " putting them in something like routes/admin.php and loading that file in the app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php file like the web/API routes are already." I do but give a mistake

Comment: Just create a file like the existing ones in `routes`, and mimic how they're loaded in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`. If you're getting errors, let us know what they **are**.

Comment: I should add middleware in the Kernel file. The reason for the error was.